# Highcharts Stacked Bar: How to remove spacing between bars

Tags: highcharts

I'm working with the highcharts stacked bar and want to remove some space between the bars so I can make room for some text I am rendering.

I've tried pointPadding and groupPadding but those are not working. I've tried minPadding/maxPadding on the xAxis and that did not do anything as well.

Seems the only way get rid of that space is to change the width of the whole chart which is what I really don't want.

Here is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/nick1572/dfcysj39/

```
$("#profit-chart").highcharts({

        lang: {
            thousandsSep: ","
        },
        chart: {
            type: "column",
            style: {
                fontFamily: "Open Sans, sans-serif"
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text: ""
        },
        xAxis: {
            //minPadding: 20, Not working here
            //maxPadding:1, Not working here either

            categories: [ "other business", "somekind of business profit" ],
            labels: {
                style: {
                    color: "#333333",
                    fontSize: "15px"
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            gridLineDashStyle: "longdash",
            title: {
                text: "Dollars"
            },
            labels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function() {
                    return "$" + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0, "", ",");
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {


            column: {
                stacking: "normal",
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: "white",
                    inside: true,
                    useHTML: true,
                    style: {
                        fontSize: "18px",
                        fontWeight: "600"
                    }
                }
            },
            series: {
                //pointPadding: 0,
                //groupPadding: 0, this does not work
                animation: {
                    complete: function() {

                    }
                },

                 pointWidth: 145
            }
        },

        series: [ {
            color: "#327631",
            data: [ 0, 850 ],
            stack: "female",
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function() {
                    if (0 != this.y) return "$" + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0); 


                    else return null;
                }
            }

            }, {
            color: "#ADC9AD ",
            data: [ 10000, 10000 ],
            stack: "female",
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function() {
                    return "$" + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0);
                }
            }
        }]

        },

        function (chart) { // on complete

                chart.renderer.text('<span class="bracketed">}</span>  <em>Profit</em>', 870, 85)
                    .css({
                        color: 'green',
                        fontSize: '24px',
                        x: 200
                    })
                    .add();


    });//End HighCharts Call
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the point width setting is conflicting with the groupPadding and pointPadding .. if you remove the `pointWidth: 145` in the series and add groupPadding and pointPadding to the column you will get the gap removed. on the flipside however the bars will take up the entire available width of your chart.

```
 column: {
         stacking: "normal",
         groupPadding: 0,//add here
         pointPadding: 0,//add here
         ...
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dfcysj39/9/

Comment: Ugh thank you. I tried playing with that. Doesnt seem to do what I need. I also tried to set a zIndex to the rendered text - right now it is cut of from the chart. The zIndex attr doesnt work. :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I think this may solve my problem at this point. Not sure if its the right way but it works. The pointPadding and groupPadding partially worked for this particular problem. I thank you Birgit for taking the time to respond!!!

What I did to solve this is explicitly put a spacingRight on the chart to give the plot area more space w/o making the bars wider. I did go back and add some pointPadding to make the cols a little wider for aesthetics. This allowed for the rendered text to show.

http://jsfiddle.net/nick1572/dfcysj39/

```
$("#profit-chart").highcharts({

        lang: {
            thousandsSep: ","
        },
        chart: {
            spacingRight: 220,
            type: "column",
            width: 1200,
            style: {
                fontFamily: "Open Sans, sans-serif"
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text: ""
        },
        xAxis: {
            //minPadding: 20, Not working here
            //maxPadding:1, Not working here either
            categories: [ "other business", "somekind of business profit" ],
            labels: {
                style: {
                    color: "#333333",
                    fontSize: "15px"
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            gridLineDashStyle: "longdash",
            title: {
                text: "Dollars"
            },
            labels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function() {
                    return "$" + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0, "", ",");
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {


            column: {
                stacking: "normal",
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: "white",
                    inside: true,
                    useHTML: true,
                    style: {
                        fontSize: "18px",
                        fontWeight: "600"
                    }
                }
            },
            series: {
                pointPadding: 0.05,
                //groupPadding: 0, this does not work
                animation: {
                    complete: function() {

                    }
                }//,

                 //pointWidth: 145
            }
        },

        series: [ {
            color: "#327631",
            data: [ 0, 850 ],
            stack: "female",
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function() {
                    if (0 != this.y) return "$" + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0); 


                    else return null;
                }
            }

            }, {
            color: "#ADC9AD ",
            data: [ 10000, 10000 ],
            stack: "female",
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function() {
                    return "$" + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0);
                }
            }
        }]

        },

        function (chart) { // on complete

                chart.renderer.text('<span class="bracketed">}</span>  <em>Profit</em>', 900, 84)
                    .css({
                        color: 'green',
                        fontSize: '24px',
                        x: 200
                    })
                    .add();


    });//End HighCharts Call
```